# How to prove that $f(x,y)=y-x$ is continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}:(x,y)\mapsto y-x$ be a function.

How do I prove that $f$ is continuous?

---

[From a comment]

I'm trying to show the famous equality $\Gamma(z)\Gamma(w)=\Gamma(z+w)B(z,w)$ (Gamma and Beta functions). I found that a function which arises in that proof, is continuous, hence measurable if $\{(x,y):0<x<y\}$ is open in $\mathbb R^2$. So I want to know whether $f$ in my post is continuous. It's geometrically trivial, but I find it hard to prove it via $ϵ−δ$ criteria.

Comment: This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Comment: take left and right limit  at some point and also  function value at this point,if they all are equal,then you have done

Comment: check the partial derivatives

Comment: @Nicholas It's OK to use all elementary analysis techinques. I'm studying continuity of 2-tuple functions since i feel hard to apply Fubini's theorem to integrals..

Comment: @dato how do you define left and right limit in complex plane?

Comment: What you're allowed to use is not at all what I was asking:  what have you tried?  Where are you getting stuck?  This is a very straight-forward problem; so, unless we know what your stumbling point is, it is very difficult to give you any help that doesn't completely give it away.

Comment: You need to show that for any point $(\hat{x},\hat{y})$ and any $\epsilon>0$ that there exists some $\delta>0$ such that if $\|(x,y)-(\hat{x},\hat{y})\| < \delta $ then $|(y-x)-(\hat{y}-\hat{x})| < \epsilon$.

Comment: @Nicholas I'm trying to show the famous equality $\Gamma(z)\Gamma(w)=\Gamma(z+w)B(z,w)$ (Gamma and Beta functions). I found that a function which arises in that proof, is continuous, hence measurable if $\{(x,y):0<x<y\}$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^2$. So i want to know whether $f$ is my post is continuous. It's geometrically trivial, but i find it hard to prove it via $\epsilon-\delta$ criteria.

Comment: @copper.hat that is exactly what i'm asking. How do i find such $\delta$ for a given $\epsilon$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

Take a point $(x_0,y_0)\in\mathbb{R}^2$. For any point $(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2$, we can write
$$
(x,y)=(x_0,y_0)+(\Delta x,\Delta y),\qquad \Delta x:=x-x_0,\qquad \Delta y:=y-y_0.
$$
Then
$$
f(x,y)-f(x_0,y_0)=(x-y)-(x_0-y_0)=(x-x_0)-(y-y_0)=\Delta x-\Delta y.
$$
Given $\epsilon>0$, you want to find $\delta>0$ such that whenever $d((x,y),(x_0,y_0))<\delta$, you have $\lvert f(x,y)-f(x_0,y_0)\rvert<\epsilon$.

Note, however, that 
$$
d((x,y),(x_0,y_0))=\sqrt{\Delta x^2+\Delta y^2},
$$
and by the above
$$
\lvert f(x,y)-f(x_0,y_0)\rvert=\lvert \Delta x-\Delta y\rvert\leq\lvert\Delta x\rvert+\lvert \Delta y\rvert.
$$
Can you see how to make $\lvert\Delta x\rvert$ and $\lvert \Delta y\rvert$ small by choosing $\delta$ small?

Of course, alternatively, you can prove that the functions $(x,y)\mapsto x$ and $(x,y)\mapsto y$ are continuous, and the (very direct) theorem that if $g$ and $h$ are continuous, then $g(x,y)-h(x,y)$ is also continuous.

Comment: The last paragraph is very helpful. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Use the Euclidean norm on $\mathbb{R}^2$. That is $\|(x,y)-(\hat{x},\hat{y})\| \le \sqrt{(x-\hat{x})^2 + (y-\hat{y})^2}$.

In this case we have $|y-x-(\hat{y}-\hat{x})| \le |y-\hat{y}| + |x-\hat{x}| \le \|(x,y)-(\hat{x},\hat{y})\|+ \|(x,y)-(\hat{x},\hat{y})\|$,
so if we choose $\delta = {\epsilon \over 2}$, then we get
$|f(x,y)-f(\hat{x},\hat{y})| \le 2 \|(x,y)-(\hat{x},\hat{y})\| < \epsilon$.